# Как сформировать блоки циклом?

Tags: javascript

Ребят не могу понять как осуществить задуманное.

Есть массив вида:

```
[
  {
    name: "A-1",
  }, {
    name: "A-2",
  }, {
    name: "B-1",
  }, {
    name: "B3",
  }, {
    name: "B5",
  }
];
```

Нужно перебрать его таким образом чтобы вывести что то вроде параграфа с первым символом из name
т.е. чтобы в html можно было получить вот такую картину

[image]

В HTML нужно получить что то вроде того

```
<div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div style="float: left;margin: 0 30px 0 0">
        <div style="color: #c0c0c0;float: left;margin-right: 10px;">A</div>
        <ul style="overflow: hidden;">
            <li>A3</li>
            <li>A4</li>
            <li>A5</li>
            <li>A6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left;margin: 0 30px 0 0">
        <div style="color: #c0c0c0;float: left;margin-right: 10px;">B</div>
        <ul style="overflow: hidden;">
            <li>B3</li>
            <li>B4</li>
            <li>B5</li>
            <li>B6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Делаю большой блок меню, в нем ссылок очень много, нужно их отсортировать таким вот макаром, а как это сделать ума не приложу =(

Уже день мучаюсь над этим вопросом, так ничего толкового и не получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@webphp](/users/18965/webphp)](/users/18965/webphp)

```
var list = [
  {
    name: "A-1",
  }, {
    name: "A-2",
  }, {
    name: "B-1",
  }, {
    name: "B3",
  }, {
    name: "B5",
  }
];
var sortedData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var name = list[i].name;
    var char = name[0];
    if (!(char in sortedData)) {
        sortedData[char] = [];
    }
    sortedData[char].push(name);
}
```